# Error with Rake asset:precompile

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy my app on a server with Capistrano.
I ran the deploy:setup, and deploy:check with success.

Some of the task of deploy:update passed with success, but the **deploy:asset:precompile** task seems to crash ruby.

I tried to understand the cause of the error :
 It seems that the issue is linked to **Rails Asset Pipeline** and **postgresql_adapter**.

I'm a bit lost as I don't much about asset pipeline. The least that I know is that Asset Pipeline has to do with javascript and CSS stylsheet, so I don't understand what postgresql_adapter is doing in here ?

These are my (server and workstation) versions :

- Rails 3.2.8
- RVM 1.16.17
- Gem 1.8.24
- Bundler 1.2.1
- pg gem 0.14.1

I also tried to run the commande **bundle exec rake assets:precompile** on the server, and the result was the same. So problem is linked to this command.

This is a summary of the error I got :

```
  * 2012-11-09 16:54:21 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /var/www/opf/releases/20121109155419 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["192.168.5.200"]
    [192.168.5.200] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.168.5.200] /var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213: [BUG] Segmentation fault
 ** [out :: 192.168.5.200] ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

This is my config/deploy.rb in any case :

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'deploy') + '/capistrano_database'

set :rvm_type, :system

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p194@rail3dev20120606'
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :application, 'opf'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/opf'
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :user, 'the_user'
set :use_sudo, false

set :group_writable, false
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  'git@github.com:user/opf.git'
set :branch, 'master'

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

server '192.168.5.200', :web, :app, :db, :primary => true

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Help is really welcome, as I have no idea where to look at.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a solution !

First know that the erro message that PhusionPassenger was displaying  :

```
Passenger encountered the following error:
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error
```

had nothing to do with gems, though it may usually be the case as explained [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/8049-how-to-fix-passenger-unexpected-end-of-file-detected-error).

You can find my solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656949/1640771).