# rake db:reset failing because of postgresql_adapter.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

I'm deploying my first railsapp on a debian server with postgresql.

Rails 3.2.9
Ruby 1.9.3-p327
pg 0.14.1

After deployment, when I do a

`bundle exec rake db:reset`

it fails with following error :

```
/var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

and a long list of error messages.

Though my database.yml is working properly on my dev worksation :

I can't find a reason why postgresql_adapter is causing an error.

--- update

If I put incorrect database name, user name and password, the result is the same.
I tested the db connection with psql my_db my_user and it works.
If I do a

`bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=production`

I got an error :

```
undefined method `sass' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000000dea738>
```

Though **sass**, **sass-rails** and **haml-rails** gem are present in my /var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems

====== UPDATE =======

Here it is my database.yml :

```
development:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydevdb
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: mypass

test:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: mytestdb
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: mypass

production:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myproddb
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: mypass
```

Here it is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
# Ressource : https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg
gem 'pg', '>= 0.14'
# https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.3'

group :developpement do
  # Ressource : https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.11'
  # Ressource : https://rvm.io//integration/capistrano/
  gem 'capistrano', '>= 2.12'
  # Ressource : https://github.com/btelles/faker
  gem 'faker', '>= 1.0'
  # Ressource : https://rvm.io//integration/capistrano/
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

group :test do 
  gem 'rspec', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'webrat', '>= 0.7'
  gem 'spork-rails', '>= 3.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 4.0'
end

group :assets do
  # Faciliter la rédaction de feuilles de style CSS
  # Ressource : http://sass-lang.com/
  gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.2.1'
  # Ressource : http://compass-style.org/
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.0'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
  #readme for more supported runtimesa
  # execjs and therubyracer are ncessary for compass-rails gem to work properly
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
# Ressource : https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models
gem 'annotate'
# Ressource : https://github.com/asanghi/excel_rails
gem 'excel_rails', '~> 0.3'
# Ressource : https://github.com/voraz/spreadsheet
gem 'spreadsheet', '~> 0.7'
# Ressource : https://github.com/lomba/schema_plus
gem 'schema_plus', '~> 0.4'
# Resource : https://github.com/tchandy/octopus
gem 'ar-octopus', '~> 0.3'
# Resource : https://github.com/ernie/squeel
gem 'squeel', '~> 1.0'
# Resource : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
gem 'devise', '~> 2.1'
# Resource : https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model
gem 'role_model'
# Resource : https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization
gem 'declarative_authorization'
# Resource : https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes
gem 'rails-translate-routes', '~> 0.1'
```

I made more tests, and realized that the issue comes from the initialization process.
At some point the Initialization of my app makes the Ruby interpreter to crash.
I removed some lines of my config/application.rb. The result was at least to change the crash into an error about "unitialized Constant Devise". I googled and found that I add to add a "require 'devise'" in my application.rb. So I did, but the error and Ruby crash came again.

The issue seems somehow linked to Asset Pipeline and Initialization.
I noticed that the following line made my Initialization to crash Ruby interpreter, so I commented it :

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

My config/application.rb :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Without this I got a "unitialized Constant Devise" error
require 'devise'

# THIS ALL STUFF MAKES CRASH RAILS INITIALIZATION, so I commented it.
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  #Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Opf
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # Pour utiliser la traduction française des messages d'erreur standards
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = 'fr'

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # =======  DEBUG : without this, Capistrano Assets:precompile crash ========
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    # ==============================================================

   # Make crashing Initialization, so I commented
#    config.generators do |g|
#      g.test_framework :rspec
#      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl
#      g.stylesheets false
      # cette option ne doit pas être activée car elle est géré (et activée) par la gem 'haml-rails'
#      # g.template-engine :haml
#    end

#    config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass

    # To replace 'div' by 'span' within error-feedbacks
    config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
      # Ressources : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t
      # Ressources : Railcast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error?autoplay=true
      class_attr_index = html_tag.index('class="')
      if class_attr_index
        html_tag.insert class_attr_index+7, 'field_with_errors '
      else
        html_tag.insert html_tag.index('>'), ' class="field_with_errors"'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Summary of successfuls tests for myapp :

- Postgresql database user access and equal to database.yml = WORK
- Gems presence in @global gemset = CHECK
- Create a 'test' application from    scratch directly on the server =
  WORK

Comment: post your database.yaml file and can i ask, you run server on local development with no problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the command without bundle exec? Also, can you show the contents of your Gemfile?

Comment: @ Kien : application run like a charm on my developement station. I will update with database.yml

Comment: @ Leo : wit or without bundle exec, the result is the same. I will update with my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some very loooong research and tests, I find out the cause of the issue.

There was several mistakes :

- In order that execjs gem works properly, the

  `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby`

must be in production group or outside any group in the Gemfile

- In order precompiling of nested SASS-CSS assets works (`rake assets:precompile`) the manifest (the comments) must be removed at the top of the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass (I'm using sass-rails and haml-rails gems), AND [I had to add the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555714/why-does-rake-assetsprecompile-produce-an-empty-css-stylesheet) :

  `@import screen.css.sass`

in my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass file.

- In order bundler works properly, I got a message during "gem install bundler" to add `$PATH:` in my /etc/profile and /root/.bashrc files on the server side.
- In order capistrano deploy:update task works properly, dont forget to add `require 'rvm/capistrano'` in your config/deploy.rb file so capistrano can find (and execute) the `bundle` command.

But with all those fix, I still got the same error with postgresql :

```
/var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

As I'm using this special [recipe](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/) in order to avoid storing database.yml on github.
And using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365950/require-in-capistrano-deploy-rb-cannot-find-file) in order capistrano find my recipe file.
I built a database.yml template for this recipe, but somehow I realize the problem was coming from my template.

I had to remove those two lines on each database in order rails initialization worked properly :

```
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Maybe the resulting database.yml was corrupt, I didn't test to re-add these (corrects) two lines. I already spent weeks on this...

--- general advices ---

Now I give some advice to developers who are desesparate to find a solution to their issue (like I was) : after a fair amout of search for solution STOP it.

Just build a new very-basic rails app with `rails new newapp --database=postgresql` (use `rails new -h` for help on database parameter for this command), then generate a simple scaffold with `rails generate scaffold mymodel mycolumn`.

In your application directory, Initialize Git with `git init` and Capistrano with `capify .`
Then just add the gem for your database (pg for instance for postgresql), run bundle install.
Then connect it to your database with you own basic database.yml, make you test to see it works on your dev workstation.
Commit and push to your Git repository, then deploy with capistrano and check it works on the server side.

Then progressively add (gems, migrations, and your own personal lib) to your newapp until it doesn't work.

In parallel add the bit that work from newapp to your failing application on the server side untill it works (don't change anything on your app on your dev workstation side).

This will lead you to the solution sooner or later.