# Why does Rails initialization fail?

Tags: initialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

I'm using Rails 3.2.9 with Ruby 1.9.3-p327.

After a 'capistrano' deploy on my server I'm unable to initialize my Rails application because it causes an error that make crash Rails and Ruby interpreter.

Without any explicit error message I must rely on backtrace, control frame and memory dump. So it is really hard to debug and find out where does come the error from. It is too long to post it here.

During the deploy, I had to set this in my **config/application.rb** file, to get the deploy:asset:precompile task to pass, otherwise I was stuck in a ruby crash :

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

After the deploy, I just ran a rake db:reset to test access to database from my application, but this lead to crash, so I tested access to my database from console and from "newly-Rails-app-directly-created-on-the-server". Everything works well on this side (database is created, and access are granted). So I exclude any issue coming from database.yml or postgres database setting.

Moreover, after some very long search (I spent an entire week on this issue) I managed to located the issue was coming from Rails Initialization.

More specifically these lines in my config/application.rb is causing a crash of Rails and Ruby.

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

I tried the two options, both of them make the application to crash. I also tried to comment them but something else make Rails and Ruby crashing as well somewhere after application.rb is read by Rails.

I suspect something linked with bundler and gem asset pipeline.
If I run a **gem list** command, I can see that bundler is installed on my server with several version :

```
bundler (1.2.1, 1.1.4, 1.1.3)
```

If I run a rvm gemset list, I see that the default gemset is in use and there arn't any other :

```
gemset for ruby-1.9.3-p327 (found in /usr/local/rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p327
=> (default)
   global
```

I don't know how to make sure Rake/Rails is using this gemset and this version of ruby ?

Moreover if I'm connected as root; **bundle install** will result with following error :

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first
```

While if connected as user it will work.

**Note that rvm has been installed as system wide with "sudo".**

My others gems are managed by bundler and stored into :
**/var/www/opf/shared/bundle/ruby/**

My Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.14'
gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.3'

group :developpement do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'capistrano', '>= 2.12'
  gem 'faker', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

group :test do 
  gem 'rspec', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'webrat', '>= 0.7'
  gem 'spork-rails', '>= 3.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 4.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'excel_rails', '~> 0.3'
gem 'spreadsheet', '~> 0.7'
gem 'schema_plus', '~> 0.4'
gem 'ar-octopus', '~> 0.3'
gem 'squeel', '~> 1.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.1'
gem 'role_model'
gem 'declarative_authorization'
gem 'rails-translate-routes', '~> 0.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found a solution !

First know that the erro message that PhusionPassenger was displaying  :

```
Passenger encountered the following error:
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error
```

had nothing to do with gems, though it may usually be the case as explained [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/8049-how-to-fix-passenger-unexpected-end-of-file-detected-error).

You can find my solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656949/1640771).