# Why does rake assets:precompile produce an empty css stylesheet?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, haml, asset-pipeline

I'm using **sass-rails** and **haml-rails** gems, so that I can write css file in HAML-sass style.

The thing is when I want to go for production and precompile my stylesheet, the command `rake assets:precompile` run without error but the generated application.css is empty.

Here it is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.14'
gem 'haml-rails' #, '~> 0.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :developpement do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'capistrano', '>= 2.12'
  gem 'faker', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'webrat', '>= 0.7'
  gem 'spork-rails', '>= 3.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'excel_rails' #, '~> 0.3'
gem 'spreadsheet' #, '~> 0.7'
gem "schema_plus", :git => "git://github.com/lomba/schema_plus.git"
gem 'ar-octopus' #, '~> 0.3'
gem 'squeel' #, '~> 1.0'
gem 'devise' #, '~> 2.1'
gem 'role_model'
gem 'declarative_authorization'
gem 'rails-translate-routes'  #, '~> 0.1'
gem 'validates_timeliness'  #, '~> 3.0'
```

Here it is my (empty) app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */
```

I removed the following commented lines as per recommandation on https://github.com/rails/sass-rails :

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

my css.sass files are stored here :

- app/assets/stylesheets/screen.css.sass
- app/assets/stylesheets/partials/ (many partials files _*.css.sass referenced by screen.css.sass)

=== UPDATE ===

Please note I'm using COMPASS gem. So mixin and variables need to be shared between stylesheets.

Just in case, this is my app/assets/stylsheets/screen.css.sass file :

```
// This import applies a global reset to any page that imports this stylesheet.
@import blueprint/reset

// To configure blueprint, edit the partials/base.sass file.
@import partials/base

@import blueprint/interaction
@import blueprint/typography
@import blueprint/grid
@import blueprint/buttons
@import blueprint/utilities

@import compass/layout/grid-background
@import compass/typography/lists/inline-block-list
@import compass/typography/lists/horizontal-list
@import compass/utilities/general/float
@import compass/css3/border-radius
@import compass/css3/box-shadow
@import compass/css3/text-shadow
@import compass/css3/transition

@import partials/opf_mixins_et_functions
@import partials/link_icons
@import partials/typo
@import partials/application
@import partials/affichage_donnees
@import partials/tableau_edition
@import partials/page
@import partials/form
@import partials/feedback
```

=== UPDATE 2 ===

I realized that my Gemfile will lead me to trouble in production because I put the following Gems in the **assets group** :

```
group :assets do
  ...
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  ...
end
```

Because **Production** environnement as well needs a javascript interpreter...
So I will move them outside of any group in my Gemfile.

Any advice welcome

Comment: Are you including your stylesheets on specific pages?  Have you set your environment file to compile those stylesheets nested in your partials folders?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. I got one rail's standard stylsheet : screen.css.sass wich reference partial stylsheets in app/assets/stylesheets partial directory. I didn't modified any environnement file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it with the following solution :

Following the spirit of the last answer, it appears that adding the following line at the end of my /app/assets/styelsheets/application.css.sass solved my issue :

```
@import screen
```

Every referenced *partial stylesheet* by screen.css.sass will then be automatically imported.

Answer (score 1):

You're recommended to remove those two lines but you still need to include yourself your files :

```
*= require screen
*= require_dir partials/
```

Do note something, however : this doesn't work like `@import` - you won't get your mixins and variable shared. Use a real `@import` for that

Comment: I thought sass-rail was following CoC (Convention over Configuration) rail's philosophy. Are you saying I do have to @import separately each of those : screen.css.sass, and all the partial stylsheets screen.css.sass is referencing  to (in : app/assets/stylsheets/partials/) ? As I'm using COMPASS, I need mixins and variable to be shared. So sprocket "require screen" and "require_dir partials/" is forbidden for me.

Comment: If you don't want to use the two directives you removed, yes you have. Or use application.css.scss and `@import` yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

My precompiled assets (application.js and application.css) were empty ...

What solved the problem for me :

- set the last rails version in Gemfile (3.2.14 for now)
- `bundle update`
- `bundle install`
- restart the app `touch tmp/restart.txt`